Cmake build raises Error Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073
In one of my projects I update the version of used OS lib (JsonCpp if interested).
It is working on a few platforms but my change fails when generating solution on Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 . These area all compiled Windows targets, others seem to be fine
I needed to make changes in some CMakeLists.txt files, but currently one of checks (as CMake sub-project) fails with following :
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VC\\v160\\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5):
error MSB3073: The command "setlocal SDM    
error MSB3073: Release\\jsoncpp_test.exe  
error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd 
error MSB3073: :cmEnd 
error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone 
error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
error MSB3073: exit /b %1  
error MSB3073: :cmDone  
error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd 

this is nothing I remotely touched, I mostly suppose some bug in CMake files.
I tried in Windows Powershell as MINGW64 (got used to Linux utils) one of build commands " cmake --build build --config Release " but this was first to fail in a chain.
It needs to be handled in code for the system, local workarounds like 'run as admin/ root' are not for this case :/
Does it "ring a bell" to anyone?
Thanks in advance

You have updated the JsonCpp library, and exactly its executable causes the error. Why do you suspect bug in CMake files in the first place? In any case the information you provide in the question post is not sufficient to understand the error, so we cannot help you in fixing it.
